Sticky section vertical scroll animation
I need some help with positioning the div. I have three main sections with 100vh. The middle sections have six more sections. What I am trying to achieve is when the user scroll to middle section the scroll does not move to last section until it finish scrolling the child sections of main middle section. Does anyone know how I can achieve that. I have tried below solution, but its not working for me. Thanks
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import GraduationHat from "../../../assets/images/graduation-hat-01.svg";
import Building from "../../../assets/images/building-07.svg";
import Progress from "../../../assets/images/Progress bar.svg";
import AcademicPic from "../../../assets/images/academic.png";
import HandDrawn from "../../../assets/images/Hand-drawn arrow.svg";
import TherdImage from "../../../assets/images/Frame 03 image.svg";
import FiveImage from "../../../assets/images/Frame 05image.svg";
import Macbook from "../../../assets/images/Macbook Pro mockup.svg";

import Image from "next/image";
import { StickyScroll } from "@/components/animations/StickyScroll";

const content = [
    {
        step: "step 1",
        title: "Uncovering the best man power from college",
        description:
            "Talent Harbor is uncovering its treasure trove by bridging the industry-academic gap.",
        image: AcademicPic,
        content: (
            <div className="h-[90%] w-fit  flex items-center justify-center">
                <Image
                    src="https://talrop-erp-static-media-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/static/talent-harbour/green-convo.svg"
                    width={1200}
                    height={800}
                    className="h-full w-full object-cover"
                    alt="linear board demo"
                />
            </div>
        ),
    },
    {
        step: "step 2",

        title: "Providing Industry Training",
        description:
            "Gain valuable insights and skills from industry experts through training programs.",
        image: Macbook,
        content: (
            <div className="h-[90%] w-fit  flex items-center justify-center">
                <Image
                    src="https://talrop-erp-static-media-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/static/talent-harbour/Step 3 - Take training for your chosen job.svg"
                    width={1200}
                    height={800}
                    className="h-full w-full object-cover"
                    alt="linear board demo"
                />
            </div>
        ),
    },
    {
        step: "step 3",

        title: "Providing Real World Experience",
        description:
            "A real project featuring a real team, offering students the chance to collaborate and contribute while still in college.",
        image: TherdImage,

        content: (
            <div className="h-[90%] w-fit  flex items-center justify-center">
                <Image
                    src="https://talrop-erp-static-media-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/static/talent-harbour/orange-convo.svg"
                    width={1200}
                    height={800}
                    className="h-full w-full object-cover"
                    alt="linear board demo"
                />
            </div>
        ),
    },
    {
        step: "step 4",

        title: "Explore a wide range of career paths",
        description:
            "Discover endless possibilities by exploring various industries, using your talents to make a meaningful impact and achieve success.",
        image: Macbook,

        content: (
            <div className="h-[90%] w-fit  flex items-center justify-center">
                <Image
                    src="https://talrop-erp-static-media-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/static/talent-harbour/Step 2 - Choose your desired job.svg"
                    width={1200}
                    height={800}
                    className="h-full w-full object-cover"
                    alt="linear board demo"
                />
            </div>
        ),
    },
    {
        step: "step 5",

        title: "Start shaping your career in college",
        description:
            "Unlock a world of career possibilities by securing access to the best opportunities available.",
        image: FiveImage,
        content: (
            <div className="h-[90%] w-fit  flex items-center justify-center">
                <Image
                    src="https://talrop-erp-static-media-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/static/talent-harbour/violet-convo.svg"
                    width={1200}
                    height={800}
                    className="h-full w-full object-cover"
                    alt="linear board demo"
                />
            </div>
        ),
    },
];
export function StickyScrollRevealDemo() {
    const scrollableSectionRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [activateCustomScroll, setActivateCustomScroll] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkIfSectionCentered = () => {
            const section = scrollableSectionRef.current;
            if (!section) return;
            const sectionTop = section?.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            const sectionHeight = section?.offsetHeight;
            const sectionMidpoint = sectionTop + sectionHeight / 2;
            const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
            const viewportMidpoint = viewportHeight / 2;
            const isSectionCentered =
                Math.abs(sectionMidpoint - viewportMidpoint) < 100; // 100px threshold for "centered"
            setActivateCustomScroll(isSectionCentered);
        };
        const handleWindowScroll = (event: any) => {
            if (activateCustomScroll) {
                const scrollAmount = event.deltaY;
                const section =
                    scrollableSectionRef.current &&
                    (scrollableSectionRef.current as HTMLElement);

                if (section) {
                    const maxScrollTop =
                        section?.scrollHeight - section?.clientHeight; // Maximum scrollTop value
                    const currentScrollTop = section?.scrollTop;

                    if (
                        (scrollAmount > 0 &&
                            currentScrollTop >= maxScrollTop) ||
                        (scrollAmount < 0 && currentScrollTop <= 0)
                    ) {
                    } else {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        section.scrollTop += scrollAmount;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener("scroll", checkIfSectionCentered);
        window.addEventListener("wheel", handleWindowScroll, {
            passive: false,
        });
        checkIfSectionCentered();
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", checkIfSectionCentered);
            window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleWindowScroll);
        };
    }, [activateCustomScroll]);

    console.log("activateCustomScroll", activateCustomScroll);

    return (
        <div className="wrapper max-ml:pt-[64px] max-ml:pb-[34px] sticky top-[50%] translate-y-[-50%] z-10">
            <StickyScroll
                content={content}
                scrollableSectionRef={scrollableSectionRef}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

"use client";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useMotionValueEvent, useScroll } from "framer-motion";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { cn } from "../utils/cn";

import Image from "next/image";

export const StickyScroll = ({
    content,
    contentClassName,
    scrollableSectionRef,
}: {
    content: {
        step: string;
        title: string;
        description: string;
        image: any;
        content?: React.ReactNode | any;
    }[];
    contentClassName?: string;
    scrollableSectionRef: any;
}) => {
    const [activeCard, setActiveCard] = React.useState(0);

    const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
        // uncomment line 22 and comment line 23 if you DONT want the overflow container and want to have it change on the entire page scroll
        // target: ref
        container: scrollableSectionRef,
        offset: ["start start", "end start"],
    });
    const cardLength = content.length;

    useMotionValueEvent(scrollYProgress, "change", (latest) => {
        const cardsBreakpoints = content.map((_, index) => index / cardLength);
        const closestBreakpointIndex = cardsBreakpoints.reduce(
            (acc, breakpoint, index) => {
                const distance = Math.abs(latest - breakpoint);
                if (distance < Math.abs(latest - cardsBreakpoints[acc])) {
                    return index;
                }
                return acc;
            },
            0
        );
        setActiveCard(closestBreakpointIndex);
    });

    const backgroundColors = [
        "#E3FBCC",
        "#E0F2FE",
        "#FFE6D5",
        "#E0EAFF",
        "#ECE9FE",
    ];
    const linearGradients = [
        "#66C61C",
        "#0BA5EC",
        "#EF6820",
        "#6172F3",
        "#875BF7",
    ];
    const BorderGradients = [
        "#D0F8AB",
        "#B9E6FE",
        "#F9DBAF",
        "#C7D7FE",
        "#DDD6FE",
    ];
    const CircleGradient = [
        "#E3FBCC",
        "#E0F2FE",
        "#FFE6D5",
        "#E0EAFF",
        "#ECE9FE",
    ];
    const ImageGradient = [
        "invert(60%) sepia(97%) saturate(412%) hue-rotate(48deg) brightness(93%) contrast(89%)",
        "invert(53%) sepia(93%) saturate(2698%) hue-rotate(167deg) brightness(98%) contrast(92%)",
        " invert(57%) sepia(34%) saturate(6296%) hue-rotate(348deg) brightness(96%) contrast(94%)",
        "invert(43%) sepia(66%) saturate(3288%) hue-rotate(218deg) brightness(100%) contrast(91%)",
        "invert(39%) sepia(30%) saturate(4121%) hue-rotate(235deg) brightness(99%) contrast(95%)",
    ];
    return (
        <>
            <motion.div
                animate={{
                    backgroundColor:
                        backgroundColors[activeCard % backgroundColors.length],
                }}
                className="pt-[100px] max-xl:pt-[54px] max-mss:pt-[32px] pb-[32px] px-[64px] max-ml:pb-0 max-ml:px-[32px] max-[480px]:px-[4px] rounded-[32px]"
            >
                <motion.div>
                    <div className="flex max-ml:flex-col gap-[2%] w-full justify-center items-center mb-[64px] max-lg:mb-[32px] max-sm:mb-0">
                        <h4 className="text-[48px] max-xl:text-[38px] max-lg:text-[32px] max-ml:text-[38px] max-[645px]:text-[32px] max-msm:text-[22px] max-[360px]:text-[20px] inter_semi_bold text-[#121926]">
                            Bridging
                        </h4>
                        <motion.div
                            animate={{
                                background:
                                    linearGradients[
                                        activeCard % linearGradients.length
                                    ],
                                borderColor:
                                    BorderGradients[
                                        activeCard % BorderGradients.length
                                    ],
                            }}
                            className="flex justify-center items-center gap-[8px] py-[8px] max-[360px]:py-[4px] px-[12px] max-[360px]:px-[6px] bg-[] border-[3px]  rounded-[143px] "
                        >
                            <motion.div
                                animate={{
                                    background:
                                        CircleGradient[
                                            activeCard % CircleGradient.length
                                        ],
                                }}
                                className="w-[48px] max-mss:w-[34px]  h-[48px] max-mss:h-[34px] rounded-[24px] bg-[#E3FBCC] flex items-center justify-center"
                            >
                                <motion.div
                                    animate={{
                                        filter: ImageGradient[
                                            activeCard % ImageGradient.length
                                        ],
                                    }}
                                    className="w-[34px] max-msm:w-[24px] max-msm:h-[24px] h-[34px]"
                                >
                                    <Image
                                        src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/talrop.com-react-assets-bucket/assets/images/28-03-2024/graduation-hat.svg"
                                        alt="Graduation-Hat-icon"
                                        width={100}
                                        height={100}
                                    />
                                </motion.div>
                            </motion.div>
                            <h4 className="text-[48px] max-xl:text-[38px] max-lg:text-[32px] max-ml:text-[38px] max-[645px]:text-[32px] max-[360px]:text-[18px] max-msm:text-[22px] max-mss:text-[20px]  inter_semi_bold text-[#121926]">
                                Academic - Industry
                            </h4>
                            <motion.div
                                animate={{
                                    background:
                                        CircleGradient[
                                            activeCard % CircleGradient.length
                                        ],
                                }}
                                className="w-[48px] h-[48px] max-mss:w-[34px] max-mss:h-[34px] rounded-[24px] bg-[#E3FBCC] flex items-center justify-center"
                            >
                                <motion.div
                                    animate={{
                                        filter: ImageGradient[
                                            activeCard % ImageGradient.length
                                        ],
                                    }}
                                    className="w-[34px] max-msm:w-[24px] max-msm:h-[24px] h-[34px] "
                                >
                                    <Image
                                        src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/talrop.com-react-assets-bucket/assets/images/28-03-2024/building.svg"
                                        alt="Building-icon"
                                        width={100}
                                        height={100}
                                    />
                                </motion.div>
                            </motion.div>
                        </motion.div>
                        <h4 className="text-[48px] max-xl:text-[38px] max-lg:text-[32px] max-ml:text-[38px]  max-[645px]:text-[32px] max-msm:text-[22px] max-[360px]:text-[20px] inter_semi_bold text-[#121926]">
                            Gap
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </motion.div>
                <motion.div
                    className="h-[23rem] max-xl:h-[15rem] max-ml:h-[30rem] max-sm:h-[28rem] max-msm:h-[25rem] max-[360px]:h-[22.5rem] overflow-y-auto flex justify-between max-ml:justify-center relative space-x-10"
                    ref={scrollableSectionRef}
                >
                    <div className=" relative flex items-start max-ml:w-full max-ml:justify-center">
                        <div className="max-w-[420px] max-ml:max-w-[80%] max-sm:max-w-[90%]">
                            {content.map((item, index) => (
                                <div
                                    key={item.title + index}
                                    className="my-28 max-xl:my-14 first-of-type:mt-12 max-xl:first-of-type:mt-12 max-ml:first-of-type:mt-[1rem] last-of-type:mb-16 max-lg:last-of-type:mb-8 max-md:last-of-type:mb-[4rem] max-sm:last-of-type:mb-[3rem]"
                                >
                                    <motion.span
                                        animate={{
                                            background:
                                                linearGradients[
                                                    activeCard %
                                                        linearGradients.length
                                                ],

                                            opacity:
                                                activeCard === index ? 1 : 0,
                                        }}
                                        className="py-[4px] capitalize px-[12px] mb-[8px] bg-[#66C61C] border-1 border-[#D0F8AB] rounded-[16px] text-[14px] max-msm:text-[12px] text-[#FFFFFF] text-center inter_regular"
                                    >
                                        {item.step}
                                    </motion.span>{" "}
                                    <motion.h2
                                        initial={{
                                            opacity: 0,
                                        }}
                                        animate={{
                                            opacity:
                                                activeCard === index ? 1 : 0,
                                        }}
                                        className="text-[36px] max-xl:text-[22px] max-msm:text-[18px] inter_semi_bold  mt-[8px]"
                                    >
                                        {item.title}
                                    </motion.h2>
                                    <motion.p
                                        initial={{
                                            opacity: 0,
                                        }}
                                        animate={{
                                            opacity:
                                                activeCard === index ? 1 : 0,
                                        }}
                                        className="text-[20px] max-xl:text-[16px] max-ml:mb-[24px] max-msm:text-[14px] text-[#364152] inter_regular"
                                    >
                                        {item.description}
                                    </motion.p>
                                    <motion.div
                                        initial={{
                                            opacity: 0,
                                        }}
                                        animate={{
                                            opacity:
                                                activeCard === index ? 1 : 0,
                                        }}
                                        className="max-ml:block hidden w-[90%] "
                                    >
                                        <Image
                                            src={item.image}
                                            alt="content image"
                                            width={1200}
                                            height={800}
                                        />
                                    </motion.div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                        ``
                    </div>
                    <motion.div
                        className={cn(
                            " max-ml:hidden w-[570px] max-xl:w-[480px] rounded-md sticky top-0 overflow-hidden ",
                            contentClassName
                        )}
                    >
                        {content[activeCard].content ?? null}
                    </motion.div>
                </motion.div>
            </motion.div>
        </>
    );
};

